# Swift missing types when build framework for simulator

Tags: swift, frameworks

I've a project that has (my own) framework within it.

When I build for device, everything is fine.

However when I build for simulator it seems that Alamofire is an issue. My main project requires Alamofire, and so does my framework.

In order to get Alamofire to work within my external framework I dragged the framework files into my framework - perhaps this is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to get around this was to use private pods to manage the dependencies.